# I want to load json/csv into hbase

Tags: json, csv, mapreduce, hbase, hive

I want to load JSON OR CSV into HBASE with out using any mapreduce programs as well as HIVEQL/pig support, is it possible and which one is more efficient hive-hbase or mapreduce-hbase.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Perl Script to do this;

This is my (perl generated) JSON file

```
{"c3":"c","c4":"d","c5":"tim","c2":"b","c6":"andrew","c1":"a"},"CURRENTLY20140131":{"c2":"tim2","c1":"bill2"},"THERE20140131"::{"c3":"c","c4":"d","c9":"bill2","c10":"tim2","c2":"b","c6":"andrew","c7":"bill","c5":"tim","c1":"a","c8":"tom"},"TODAY20140131":{"c2":"bill","c1":"tom"}}
```

I am Sharding on a STRING, with multiple columns depending who/what has referenced the key object.

```
    use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use JSON::XS qw(encode_json decode_json);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);

my %words = ();
my $debug = 0;

sub ReadHash {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my $json = read_file( $filename, { binmode => ':raw' } );
    %words = %{ decode_json $json };
}


# Main Starts here
ReadHash("Save.json");
foreach my $key (keys %words)
    {
        printf("put 'test', '$key',"); 
        my $cnt=0;
        foreach my $key2 ( keys %{ $words{$key} } ) {
            my $val = $words{$key}{$key2};
        print "," if $cnt>0;
            printf("'cf:$key2', '$val'");
        ++$cnt;
    }
        print "\n";
}
```

Generate the Hbase commands and then execute them.

Alternativly - I would look at happybase (Python) which also loads large data sets very quickly.

Hope this helps

This should produce output like .....

```
put 'test', 'WHERE20140131','cf:c2', 'bill2','cf:c1', 'tim2'
put 'test', 'OMAN20140131','cf:c3', 'c','cf:c4', 'd','cf:c5', 'tim','cf:c2', 'b','cf:c1', 'a','cf:c6', 'andrew'
put 'test', 'CURRENTLY20140131','cf:c2', 'tim2','cf:c1', 'bill2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to bulk loading. Here is the link.  [bulk loading](http://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html)